# Polarization rotation: Jones Matrix that maps Horizontal to right circular

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

I am looking at the [Poincaré sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare_sphere) and I am trying to compute a [Jones matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_calculus) for a particular rotation.  Specifically, I would like it to perform the following maps:

$O :|H \rangle \rightarrow |R \rangle$

$O :|V \rangle \rightarrow |L \rangle$

$O :|L \rangle \rightarrow |H \rangle$

$O :|R \rangle \rightarrow |V \rangle$

where $|R \rangle$, $|L \rangle$ are right circular and left circular light.  Is this possible?  I should mention that I would also accept the same equations with L,R replaced by linearly polarized light $|D \rangle$, $|A \rangle$.  If it is possible, what would be common plates that could do it?

Answer (score 3):

@wsc answer is interesting but misses a key point. Jones vector are defined upto a global phase, which gives us enough degree of freedom to solve your problem.
Since your operation corresponds to a $\frac\pi2$-rotation around the $Y$ axis in the Poincaré sphere, it is physically doable.

Algebraically, after the first to equations, the matrix is determined to be
$$\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}1&e^{i\phi} \\ -i&i e^{i\phi}\end{bmatrix}.$$ The third condition
imposes $\phi=-\frac\pi2$, which gives the final matrix
$$M=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}1&-i \\ -i&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
$M$ is fully determined and consistent with the fourth condition.

**Edited to add:** A little linear agebra will show you that this matrix corresponds to a quarter wave plate rotated with a $\frac\pi4$ angle relatively to the vertical direction. 
Of course, it is easy to give physical intuition after I deduced it from the algebra:

- a quarter wave plate is needed to transform a circular polarization into a linear polarization and vice-versa;
- Applying twice the transformation swaps $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$. This is what a half-wave plate at a $\frac\pi4$-angle does. And a half-wave plate is nothing more that 2 stacked quarter-wave plates (at least in theory). This gives the $\frac\pi4$-angle needed for our quarter-wave plate. QED without algebra.

Comment: Haha, oops. Forgot about that.